# Matching Java timestamp code to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, timestamp, milliseconds

I have this code which showing sets the timestamp to be in a specific format written in

Java:

```
timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
writer.write(String.format("%d, %f, %s\n", timeStamp, evt.values[1], otherstr ));
```

I am using javascript so I need to translate it.

I currently have this:

```
const timeStamp = + new Date();
console.log(timeStamp);
```

I can't test the Java one as I don't know Java so I'm asking here.

Would my javascript code match the Java timestamp?

If not, how can I match it in Javascript?

Comment: `const timeStamp = new Date().getTime()`; would give the milliseconds since 1970 on the user's computer

Comment: The Java code prints milliseconds since the Unix/Java epoch of the start of day in UTC of Jan 1, 1970. Just now the result was 1649531005118.

Comment: Some seconds later your Javascript code logged 1649531082173, so yes, they seem equivalent.